# Python String display

Tags: python

I want to display whatever is in *line1* to *line3*, which are inputs from the user. So I assign it to variable `print_out` but don't know a way how to make it work so that when it write in a text-file it is endented with `\n`. What should I put in the string?

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")  #input from user and are store in line1
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")  #input from user and are store in line2
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ") #input from user and are store in line3

print_out =    #here i want to assign line1-line 3 as string and assign it to variable print_out

txt.write(print_out) #will write whatever it is typed inside print_out on to a file
```

The question is, how do I assign stuff into `print_out`? I know a way how to do it, but that's more coding, so I want to use string to do it. The other way is:

```
txt.write(line1)
txt.write("\n")
txt.write(line2)
txt.write("\n")
txt.write(line3)
txt.write("\n")
```

But I want to use a string to display this, so I don't have to write so much. How do I do it so it display like that but using string instead of keep writing txt.write to enter new line. thanks.

Comment: From your post, I can't understand clearly what you are trying to accomplish. Could you please try and edit your question?

Comment: You should express yourself more clearly and use the available ways to format your text in order to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
print_out = txt.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(line1,line2,line3))
```

Comment: Is the return-value of `file.write` a string, or what do you expect `print_out` to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
print_out = "%s\n" * 3 % (line1, line2, line3)
txt.write(print_out)
```